# Is there a payment processor extension for Worldpay or do we need to create one?

Tags: payment-processor

Do we have a extension already in the community which allows us to use Worldpay as a payment processor? I have not found one. Do we need to create new payment processor extension for Worldpay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is [experimental code available on Github](https://github.com/idmacdonald/civicrm-worldpay) for a Worldpay processor, which might need further development.

You may also want to explore the [Omnipay extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension). It doesn't list Worldpay on the extension page yet, but there is [a driver for Worldpay with Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-worldpay) that may just need some testing and/or minor tweaks to get running with CiviCRM using the Omnipay extension.

Answer (score 3):

This is in production use on several sites https://github.com/circleinteractive/uk.co.circleinteractive.payment.worldpay

Answer (score 2):

New extension Created - Alpha version has been released

Worldpay has two Gateway one

1. secure.worldpay.com
2. online.worldpay.com

So I have created an extension for online.worldpay.com which can be accessed using API In this no more redirection to worldpay site - for more info

https://github.com/rameshrr99/uk.co.nfpservice.onlineworldpay